# parse content from wikipedia article replacing search term with the title of article

Tags: plugin-development

I have a piece of php code, which shows wikipedia article introduction. It works fine, but I need to replace search term with the title of article.

```
<?php
function getDescription($keyword){
    $url='http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString='.urlencode($keyword).'&MaxHits=1';
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($url);
    return $xml->Result->Description;
}

echo getDescription('*some term*');

?>
```

My problem is to replace `getDescription ('*some term*');` search word with title of article.

I`m trying with:

```
echo getDescription('<?php single_post_title(); ?>');
```

but it returns nothing.

My code located on other plugin (advanced ads). Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't echo something into a function's arguments. The [`single_post_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_post_title) function will echo the title by default. You should either set the second parameter to false, or use another function:

```
echo getDescription( single_post_title( '', false ) );
```

WordPress also offers the [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) function that returns the single post's title which you can use here.

So, your code should be:

```
echo getDescription( get_the_title() );
```